# Prove: There exist prime $p$ between $2c$ and $3c$ for every $c\geq3$?

Tags: number-theory

Prove or Disprove: There exist prime $p$ between $2c$ and $3c$ for every $c\geq3$ ?

Comment: Hi @ronenp , can you tell us what you have tried so far? This question would be closed otherwise, since this is not a homework solving forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is affirmative. Check out this paper: [Primes in the Interval $[2n, 3n]$](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2c0c/af5bbaa02dcb7eeeebc5044a9079fc21abfe.pdf)